# Why am I getting only part of the page when I'm requesting it?

Tags: python, python-requests

I'm trying to get website HTML in my script so I can scrape it later but I'm running into problems getting it, I am not sure why but I am only getting part of the page HTML when I'm requesting it.

First I tried requesting it with the request library when that didn't work I tried to add some headers and send this together with the request but I got confused with cookies, Do I need to send those and what should I use? Request session or basic request?

[link](https://stips.co.il/explore) to the webstie

Eventually, I came out with this function that isn't really gets me what I want:

```
def get_page_html():
    link = 'https://stips.co.il/explore'
headers={
    'Accept': 'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3',
    'Accept-Encoding': 'gzip, deflate, br',
    'Accept-Language': 'en-US,en;q=0.9',
    'Cache-Control': 'max-age=0',
    'Connection': 'keep-alive',
    'Host': 'stips.co.il',
    'Upgrade-Insecure-Requests': '1',
    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/73.0.3683.103 Safari/537.36'
}
responde = requests.post(link, headers=headers)
return responde.text
```

As I explained I got as a result of only a part of the page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The data appears to be loaded dynamically, which (in this case) is great news for us.
Pressing F12 in Chrome and navigating to the network tab reveals the underlying API call.

```
import requests

headers = {
    'Referer': 'https://stips.co.il/explore',
    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/73.0.3683.103 Safari/537.36',
    'Accept': 'application/json, text/plain, */*',
    'Origin': 'https://stips.co.il',

}

url = 'https://stips.co.il/api?name=objectlist&api_params={"method":"ask.new","safe_filter":true,"page":1}'

r = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
j = r.json()
```

The above script outputs highly structured JSON data and as you can see in the `api_params` you can iterate and update the page number each time.

Best of luck!

*Tip - Keep an eye out for rate limiters, maybe explore `time.sleep(x)` for a period of time between each request and maybe using a proxy to mask your IP.*

Comment: Thank you! I didn't know that and it helped me :)

Answer (score 2):

It seems to me that the page must be dynamically loading the content or something. The solution that I've found for this on other projects I've done is to use [the `selenium` module](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/) to load in the page in a browser object and then get the source from the page after interacting with the page in a specific way. An example you can mess around with would look something like this:

```
from selenium import webdriver
browser = webdriver.Chrome() # You'll need to download drivers from link above
browser.implicitly_wait(10) # probably unnecessary, just makes sure all pages you visit fully load
browser.get('https://stips.co.il/explore')
while True:
    input('Press Enter to print HTML')
    HTML = browser.page_source
    print(HTML)
```

This will let you see how the HTML is changing with regards to what you are doing to the page. Once you know what buttons you are trying to click on you can [locate the elements](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/locating-elements.html) and then do things like `.click()` on them automatically within the program. Once you have your script scraping all the data you need, you can run selenium in headless mode and it won't even pop up with a window on your screen! It will all be behind the scenes.

Comment: Hi @Reedinationer, I have thrown an answer in the ring. It looks like the underlying API call his coming through the network traffic that outputs very nice JSON data. Would love to hear your thoughts on my solution. I am quite new to Python.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the rest of the page content is loaded dynamically when scrolling further down. Loading of dynamic page content is usually done by javascript code that is executed by your browser.

So you will not get all the page content by only using requests library. You need to use some kind of browser simulation functionality, to put it simply.

You can implement "loading more page content" functionality by using e.g. [Selenium driver for python](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/installation.html#drivers). Furthermore, you need to add a browser, in which you can use Selenium, I used PhantomJS which is a headless browser.

**Here is a short instruction:**
1. Download the Selenium driver for your operating system
2. Download Selenium Client & WebDriver Language Bindings [here](https://www.seleniumhq.org/download/)
3. Import Virtual display
4. Import Selenium webdriver
5. Implement `scrollDown()` function

```
from pyvirtualdisplay import Display
from selenium import webdriver

with Display():
    driver = webdriver.PhantomJS()

# page scrolling functionality with selenium
def scrollDown(browser, class_name, sec, response_url):
    from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
    from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
    from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
    browser.get(response_url)
    element0 = WebDriverWait(browser, 30).until(
        EC.presence_of_all_elements_located((By.CLASS_NAME, class_name)))
    prev_part = len(element0)
    browser.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight);")
    time.sleep(sec)
    element1 = WebDriverWait(browser, 30).until(
        EC.presence_of_all_elements_located((By.CLASS_NAME, class_name)))
    curr_part = len(element1)
    while curr_part > prev_part:  # breaking condition for scrolling
        browser.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight);")
        time.sleep(sec)
        element1 = WebDriverWait(browser, 30).until(
            EC.presence_of_all_elements_located((By.CLASS_NAME, class_name)))
        prev_part = curr_part
        curr_part = len(element1)
    return browser
```

Use your `scrollDown()` function as follows:

```
driver.get(responde)
# scroll page with selenium
driver = scrollDown(driver, "divBorder3", 20, responde)
response = driver.page_source
```

It is important to analyse your page, to find out the HTML `class_name` that loads additional content, in my case, it was "divBorder3".

I hope this helps to start. You obviously have to loop over each loaded content part. I suggest using [Scrapy](https://scrapy.org) it is a web crawling framework, which cares about iterating over pages etc. If combined with Selenium or [Beautiful Soap](https://pypi.org/project/beautifulsoup4/), it is indeed very powerful.

Answer (score 0):

If you're querying an internal JSON URL, make sure you send in the proper referrer.

Also, when using Selenium, you can stop loading the page after you find the stuff you want. Don't forget to close the browser.

Comment: Please don't make more work for other people by vandalizing your posts. By posting on the Stack Exchange network, you've granted a non-revocable right, under the [CC BY-SA 3.0 license](//creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/3.0/), for Stack Exchange to distribute that content (i.e. regardless of your future choices). By Stack Exchange policy, the non-vandalized version of the post is the one which is distributed. Thus, any vandalism will be reverted. If you want to know more about deleting a post please see: [How does deleting work?](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/5221)